# Flutter Downloader: download file from URL with spaces

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using [Flutter Downloader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader) to download PDF files from an API. On Android I have no issues with the plugin, but on iOS, when the file download URL comes with a space, the file is not downloaded.

```
                    final status = await Permission.storage.request();
                if (status.isGranted) {
                  final fileType = widget.billet.uRL.split(".").last;
                  final rng = Random();
                  final externalDir = Platform.isIOS
                      ? Platform.isIOS
                          ? await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()
                          : await getExternalStorageDirectory()
                      : await getExternalStorageDirectory();
                  await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
                    url: 'https://${widget.billet.uRL}',
                    savedDir: externalDir.path,
                    fileName: '${rng.nextInt(1000).toString()}_boleto_MF7.$fileType',
                    openFileFromNotification: true,
                    showNotification: true,
                  );
                } else {
                  print('No download permission');
                }
```

Example:
File is successfully downloaded: https://company.com/arq/file_123.pdf
File is NOT downloaded successfully: https://company.com/arq/file 123.pdf

When I try to download a file on iOS with the URL with a space, I get the following alert on the console:
"Error retrieving thread information (os/kern) invalid argument"

Is there a way to pass the URL with a space?

Comment: `HttpClient` is another alternative to download files.

Comment: Try replacing space with a `+` or `%20`

Answer (score -1):

It's likely that the URL with spacing wasn't encoded properly which why the download request fails. What you can do here is encode the URL with `Uri.encodeFull(url);`